# Video in video.js-Player not displayed correctly

Tags: video.js

I have a problem regarding a video that is not displayed correctly in the video.js player:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/kakteen/zeitraffer_vjs.php?Idx=10
As you can see from the page source the dimensions of the player are set to 640x480. The video has the same dimensions which I verified by loading it into my local player and displaying the properties. But: At the left and the right of the video there is a gap of some pixels. The poster is displayed correctly without these gaps. This results in an ugly skip when the player switches from the video to the poster. The poster image is the last frame of the video.
Other videos like this one
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/zeitraffer.php?Idx=1
are playing fine without a skip but I can't find any difference between these and the faulty one.
My browser is Firefox 23.0.1 thus the ogv video is used.
Can anybody help?
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: When I open the video in a tab by itself and inspect it, it shows a "native" size of 638x524

Comment: Hallo and thank you for this information. That would explain the problems I have. However, I was not able to retrace this. I loaded the pure video in a tab but the context menu offered only "Analyze element" and "Analyze element with Firebug". I opened both but could not find information about the dimensions.

Comment: Hallo, in the meantime I was able to solve this issue. My problem was that I always looked at the ogv video but the faulty one was the mp4 video. I always understood things in that way that Firefox uses OGG and IE uses MP4. But my latest version of http://www.ulrichbangert.de/kakteen/zeitraffer_vjs.php?Idx=10 shows that FF uses the MP4 version. Can anyone explain this? I used handbrake to create the MP4 video. It showed width 640 and aspect ration 1.33. Obviously handbrake falsified the dimensions.

Comment: Recently FF for windows has adopted the .mp4 format, while FF or mac still requires the .ogg